# Help with identifying scales from track

Tags: scales

I've been studying basic drumming, and found this track on YouTube, [Prog Metal - Drumless Track For Drummers - "Reckoning"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Pi8CwjPIVs).

The tempo is 175 BPM, so to be able to listen to the notes, I slow the video down to 0.75, 0.5.

Firstly, there are 2 different though similar scales being played, and they remind me of the sound of God Chords or Space Chords, but there is also a certain Middle Eastern sound (notes, *natural 3* progression) that make both scales sound not quite Major, resulting in a somewhat mystical sound.

Secondly, the 2nd scale being played either has a delay or is actually being played in such a way as to sound as though it is delayed (if that makes sense).

Can someone please help identify both scales?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only two scales and chord types are used: Maj7 and min7.

```
1st section: B♭maj7 | B♭maj7 | A♭maj7 | Cmin7
2nd section: B♭maj7 | A♭maj7 | G♭maj7 | A♭maj7
```

It is *possible* that the aumented fourth could be used for the major chords (*lydian* scale), especially for the G♭, and the augmented sixth (*dorian* scale) for the C minor, but it doesn't seem that those notes are being played by the guitar.